# OAuth fails on one host

Tags: php, linux, macos, zend-framework, oauth

This is my code:

```
$key = "xxx";
$secret = "xxx";
$url = "https://oauth.withings.com/account";

$config = array(
    "siteUrl" => $url,
    "consumerKey" => $key,
    "consumerSecret" => $secret,
    "requestMethod" => "GET"
);
$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);

try {
    $token = $consumer->getRequestToken();
} catch (Zend_Oauth_Exception $e){
    print $e;
}
```

And when I run this on my Mac (OSX 10.8, PHP 5.3.13, Zend 1.11.12) it works as it should.

But when I run it on my Linux server (Debian 6.0.5, PHP 5.3.3, Zend 1.10.6) it fails. The Zend documentation is very thin, but did something happen between 1.10 och 1.11 that makes the same code fail? The error message is as follows:

"exception 'Zend_Oauth_Exception' with message 'Could not retrieve a valid Token response from Token URL: '"

The error seems to suggest that no URL was sent along. Now, the "siteUrl" config option seems to be the same for Zend 1.10 and 1.11 so that can't be it, right?

When constructing the URL manually and using CURL on my Linux host, I get the correct response, so it can't be a network or blocking problem.

When changing the URL to say "/accounts" (i.e. to make it an incorrect URL), it returns HTML 404 code for both the Mac and Linux using this code.

I'm at a loss here. Anyone know how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I've updated Debuan to Wheezy, PHP to 5.4.4 and Zend to 1.11 on the Linux host, and still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

404 means not found, so the server can't serve a document for the URL, shouldn't have anything to do with auth... Auth failures should be 403. If you only get the 404 with auth on, the 404 could be on redirect... You should try Charles proxy or similar to debug the requests.

Edit I reread and see the 404 was intentional... I would still try to debug the requests

Comment: I'm just not sure how I debug the request when using zend... Can i see just what request it is making?

Answer (score 0):

I found the exception in the code for `Zend_Oauth_Http` it seems as tho the response is failing a scheme check, you might want to explicitly set the scheme.

the code:

```
 /**
     * Manages the switch from OAuth request scheme to another lower preference
     * scheme during a request cycle.
     *
     * @param  Zend_Http_Response
     * @return void
     * @throws Zend_Oauth_Exception if unable to retrieve valid token response
     */
    protected function _assessRequestAttempt(Zend_Http_Response $response = null)
    {
        switch ($this->_preferredRequestScheme) {
            case Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER:
                $this->_preferredRequestScheme = Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_POSTBODY;
                break;
            case Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_POSTBODY:
                $this->_preferredRequestScheme = Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_QUERYSTRING;
                break;
            default:
                require_once 'Zend/Oauth/Exception.php';
                throw new Zend_Oauth_Exception(
                    'Could not retrieve a valid Token response from Token URL:'
                    . ($response !== null
                        ? PHP_EOL . $response->getBody()
                        : ' No body - check for headers')
                );
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for digging. I added this: "requestScheme" => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_QUERYSTRING and also tried "requestScheme" => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER, but it didn't make a difference... And how can this be different between my Mac and my Linux machine?

Comment: So, uh, looking at that function, it seems what it does is change it. Why is that? I mean, if I set preferred to querystring, it will fail. If I set it to header, this will change it to postbody and if I set it to postbody, it will change it to querystring... What the hell?

Comment: I changed this code to print out the values, and sure enough - the values goes from Header -> Body -> Fail. That's just extremely odd.

Comment: Adding the smae troubleshooting code on my Mac doesn't print anything - i.e. the function isn't being run. So why is that then? Hmmm

Comment: Ok, troubleshooting some more, it seems that it runs this function after having found that the remote server reports a status code of 500 on the request. But it doesn't when I'm requesting it from my Mac. But why?

Comment: Is it possible the apache installation on your Linux box is altering headers in some way? I assume you are using a default LAMP stack that comes with your distro. Maybe try an alternate installation like Zend Server CE which should reset the apache to work with ZF specifically.